# I installed paramiko with `pip install paramiko`, but can't import paramiko

Tags: python, macos, pip

I installed paramiko with `pip install paramiko`, but can't import paramiko

What's wrong with my python? (on mac)

[image]

Comment: Perhaps you use Python3, but installed with pip for Python2? In that case, you'll have better luck with `pip3 install paramiko`

Comment: What IDE are you using. I use VSCode and I have to choose the right Python Interpreter. Maybe you have two of them. You can easily see where is it installed after you do pip install. You can also start the python console in command prompt and try to import paramiko and see if you have it right.

Comment: you can use << pip show paramiko >> or in python 3 << pip show paramiko >> , with this command you will check exactly github link is true or not . then another way is get module from github : https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko/ . command : python3 -m pip install

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall it and install it again.

```
pip uninstall paramiko
pip install paramiko
```

edit:

> On Windows or Mac OS X, provided your pip is modern (8.x+): nothing else is required. pip will install statically compiled binary archives of Cryptography & its dependencies.
>
> On Linux, or on other platforms with older versions of pip: you’ll need a C build toolchain, plus development headers for Python, OpenSSL and libffi. Again, see Cryptography’s install docs; these requirements may occasionally change.

reference: http://www.paramiko.org/installing.html

Comment: I did, but not work

Comment: If you installed python using Anaconda, try 'conda install paramiko'